# Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: error

I am working in this app and everything works so fine and no errors so far but I accidentally click this "SFDX: Turn On Apex Debug Log for Replay Debugger" instead of new LWC so I tried to deploy and test it again then this error appear "Uncaught (in promise)". I think errors appears anytime I click any button inside the datatable. Any button outside of the datatable works fine. Can anyone help me fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning on the Apex Replay Debugger (ARD) just sets up some data in Salesforce for debugging purposes. It cannot make your previously working code stop working. The error is telling you that an Apex method failed to execute. You can expand the `pageErrors` object for more details on what happened, or you can use the "SFDX: Get Apex Debug Logs" VS Code command to retrieve recent logs, since you've turned on the ARD. You can prove that ARD isn't the problem by using the "SFDX: Turn off Apex Debug Log for Replay Debugger" menu command.

Comment: @sfdxfox Thanks I manage to fix it but the datatable won't refresh now after update. I have refresh apex at onrowaction and renderedCallBack. I look at the console and it displays the records so I think the refresh apex doesn't work or I maybe I used it incorrectly.